# Problems filtering VCF file by read depth using PyVCF

Tags: python-3.x, vcf-vcard

I am attempting to use PyVCF to filter out sites that are at or above a read depth of 10. I am aware of a built in filter to sort by read depth in PyVCF but I can't get it to work properly. Instead, I have tried to write a small script to do this myself, but the script below produces the following error: "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Can anyone help my figure out how to filter by depth read, by the filter in PyVCF or through my own script? Why am I unable to use the >= command between these instances?

```
import vcf
filename = "FR320N_shifted_ChrY.vcf"
fileoutput = "FR320N_shifted_ChrY_filtered_DP10.vcf"

vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(filename, 'r'))
vcf_writer = vcf.Writer(open(fileoutput, 'w'), vcf_reader)

for record in vcf_reader:
    if record.INFO['DP'] >= 10:
        vcf_writer.write_record(Record)
```